# How to fetch month and day from NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

How to fetch just month and date from `NSDate` and save back as date? I googled but didn't find a solution.

I tried something like this but didn't work -

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *dateString = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: Did you look at `NSDateComponents`?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?  `NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];`

Comment: (I suspect that `[arr objectAtIndex:0]` is not the value you expect, or does not match the date format.)

Comment: I am getting date in string format from this:                         NSString *dateString = [arr objectAtIndex:0]; // you can ignore this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
NSDate *theDate = ... 
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                       fromDate:theDate];
NSInteger mm = [comps month];
NSInteger dd = [comps day];
```

Comment: Please don't feed the bears.

Comment: You should be using `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger` instead of `int`, especially once the iPhone 5S goes live. Though, for this example, I think it's fine to stick with `int`. :)

Comment: When you feed the bears they keep coming back for handouts and never learn to fend for themselves.  Eventually the rangers have to shoot them.

Comment: @HotLicks In all fairness, though, fetching the date components from `NSDate` in Cocoa is far from being obvious, intuitive, or anything of that nature. One needs to use two additional classes, and to know a trick of `OR`-ing the constants. When I was working this out for myself for the first time, I wouldn't mind someone "feeding" it to me instead.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if you assume non-ARC, please make it explicit ;)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I wanted to fetch mm and dd part from my date which has mm/dd/yyyy.. I want something like 09/15 from 09/15/2013.. basically i have array of strings and I converted them to date array with mm/dd/yyyy format.. now I want to have array of dates with mm/dd format..

Comment: @user1140780 "an array of dates with mm/dd format" does not work like that, because dates and formats are independent of each other. In other words, dates do not "have" a format: you can combine a date and a format to produce a string that you desire (use `NSDateFormatter` again, this time with `@"MM/dd"`), but the date would remain unchanged.

Comment: @HotLicks I think I was not very clear in my question. I wanted to fetch the mm/dd part from date. I could have used NSDateComponents and then stored as a string or something but I was looking for built in method. I concluded that we don't have and I have to handle by writing my own method and store date as string.

Comment: @user1140780 - We still can't figure out what your original source it.  Is it an NSDate or an NSString?  If the latter, what is its format?

Comment: @HotLicks It is an array of NSString in the format - @"09/13/2013, 09/14/2013, etc.. ". I thought I can convert this to NSDate and then just extract mm/dd using some built in NSDate method. But this is not possible or just use NSDateComponents method.. I got it working by just removing /2013 part from NSString in that array. I am not converting NSDate array now..

Comment: You can convert the date to NSDate with one NSDateFormatter format, and then use a different format to create the desired month/day layout.  Requires two conversions with two different formats, but far from rocket science.

Comment: (This assumes that your array contains only one date per array entry, not several comma-separated dates in a single string as your example suggests.)